# Extending Classes with Index signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make an abstract class but things aren't working as i would like them to and i fear my knowledge of typescript is what is limiting as i think this is a fairly generic use case.

I have an abstract class Program. 
This abstract class has a bunch of functions and attributes.

```
abstract class Program {
  someString: string = "bob";
  someFunc(): void {
    return;
  }
  someOtherfunc: void {
    this.childFunc();
    return; 
  }
}
```

I also have interface 'IProgram' that looks like this

```
interface IProgram {
  childFunc: () => void; 
}
```

class Child extends class Program like so and also implements 'IProgram' interface

```
class Child extends Program implements IProgram {
  childFunc(): void {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}
```

So I cant get this to work while not getting some sort of breaking (IMHO) behavior.

I've tried to add an index signature to 'Program' 
That works i get no TS errors, but then anything works in child program. I dont care losing validations in IProgram as this isn't something that will be changed, but I don't want children program being able to go:

```
this.bob = 'potato'; //TS wont give an error because of index signature in parent
```

I've also tried declaring 'childFunc' as type any in the Abstract class but then it complains that it's supposed to be a function and not a member. My other issue with declaring it is that my child class implementing 'IProgram' will no longer be forced to implement 'childFunc' as TS finds it in the header.

I've also made a minimal stackBlitz reproducing this issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-po7hbo

I basically just want the abstract class to accept that all its children will have those funcs/properties declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you really expect all concrete subclasses of `Program` to implement `IProgram`, because you are referring to `this.childFunc()` inside the definition of `Program`.  If so, you should declare that `Program` implements `IProgram`, declare the `childFunc` method inside `Program`, and [mark it as `abstract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes):

```
abstract class Program implements IProgram {

  abstract childFunc(): void; // marked as abstract

  someString: string = "bob";
  someFunc(): void {
    return;
  };
  someOtherfunc(): void {
    this.childFunc(); // okay now
    return;
  };  
}

// you can remove the "implements IProgram" from Child since the parent has it
class Child extends Program {
  childFunc(): void {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Abstract methods are declared but not implemented in their abstract class, and all concrete subclasses will have to implement them or get an error:

```
class Oops extends Program { // error!
//    ~~~~ 
// Non-abstract class 'Oops' does not implement inherited 
// abstract member 'childFunc' from class 'Program'.
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Omg thank you so much. The only thing i didn't know was that i could make a property of a class abstract. That is what i was missing! Thank you so much for your help.